# How do i fix an error that reads "Cannot find module 'mailosaur'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, puppeteer, amazon-cloudwatch

i am running a puppeteer script and it seems i have to declare a mailosaur stack for me to proceed with my  code. I am running a node.js script in aws cloudwatch. here is me defining the stack, and the code follows suit.

```
const synthetics = require('Synthetics');
const MailosaurClient = require('mailosaur');
const log = require('SyntheticsLogger');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');
const url = require('url');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

await synthetics.executeStep('Assert the email was received', async function () {
      const mailosaur = new MailosaurClient(`${process.env.MAILOSAUR_API_KEY}`);
      const serverId = ''
      const serverDomain = `${serverId}.mailosaur.net`

      const searchCriteria = {
          sentTo: `${patientEmailAddress}@${serverDomain}`
      }

      const message = await mailosaur.messages.get(serverId, searchCriteria)
      const dom = new JSDOM(message.html.body);
      const el = dom.window.document.querySelector('p.em_defaultlink > a');
      target = el.href;
    });
```

the error reads

RROR: Canary error:
Error: Cannot find module 'mailosaur'Require stack:- /opt/nodejs/node_modules/daniels-1.js- /var/task/index.js- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js- /var/runtime/index.js Stack: Error: Cannot find module 'mailosaur'

Answer (score 1):

the error says it cannot find the module mailosaur.
you just need to install it.

you need to run

```
npm install mailosaur;
```

Comment: i am runningthis on the aws constole, do i need to introduce it as a block in my script? or do you want me to run that on my local